# (Discord.js) How to check if bot login token is valid?

Tags: discord.js

**I am trying to write a function for my program that checks if a discord bot token is valid in discord.js.** Here is a function that I tried to write which basically explains what I am trying to do

```
    bot.on('ready', () => {
        console.log("Bot is now on");
    })
    if (bot.login(id)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any possible way to check for a valid ID?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! bot.login() throws an error of invalid token if the login fails. I used try and catch in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check. It automatically does this and logs if the token was valid or not lol